# Выключение докер контейнера изнутри

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Есть несколько докер контейнеров, которые запускаются через docker-compose.
Сейчас надо создать ещё один докер, который по сути будет запускать скрипт, скрипт отработает и выйдет.. А докер будет работать дальше. ВОПРОС: можно ли как-то отключить этот простаивающий докер контейнер из docker-compose или ещё как-то, главное не руками команду прописывать?

Comment: докер контейнеры автоматически останавливаются когда завершается "главный" процесс (с id = 1), возможно вы выполняете скрипт не напрямую, а через bash, который остается открытым, поэтому контейнер и не завершается

Comment: добавте docker-compose и Dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-т я не уверен что он будет работать дальше... Вот, запускаю голый контейнер. Условно говоря запускаю в нём скрипт. Скрипт отрабатывает, завершается, вместе с ним и контейнер завершает выполнение.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]